# Why and when do I need to use the global step in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow, but I am not sure why I even need the `global_step` variable or if it is even necessary for training. I have sth like this:

gradients_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(value)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients_and_vars)

and then in my loop inside a session I do this:

```
_ = sess.run([train_op])
```

I am using a Queue to feed my data the the graph. Do I even have to instantiate a `global_step` variable?

My loop looks like this:

```
while not coord.should_stop():
```

So this loop stops, when it should stop. So why do I need the `global_step` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the global step in all cases. But sometimes people want to stop training, tweak some code and then continue training with the saved and restored model. Then often it is nice to know how long (=for how many time steps) this model had been trained so far. Thus the global step.

Also sometimes your learning rate regime might depend on the time the model already had been trained. Say you want to decay your learning rate every 100.000 steps. If you don't keep track of the number of steps already taken this might be difficult if you interrupted training in between and didn't keep track of the number of steps already taken.

And furthermore if you are using tensorboard the global step is the central parameter for your x-axis of the charts.

Comment: Okay, thank you! So I actually do not need it, but obviously it is very nice to have it! Is it important to call the `global_step` or could I also call it: `step` ?

Comment: I think it matters for tensorboard, but I'm not 100 % certain. For all other purposes the name doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, yeah for tensorboard, but not for the training itself, so if something is wrong it is not due to the `global_step`. Thanks a lot! I thought so but I was not sure.